I can't use [ngStyle] in the html tag
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top" [ngStyle]="navBg">

Html In the project I developed with Angular, the [ngStyle]="navBg" field in this tag in the HTML gives an error.
navBg: any;

  @HostListener('document:scroll') scrollover() {
    if (document.body.scrollTop > 0 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 0) {
      this.navBg = {
        "background-color": "#000000"
      }
    }
    else {
      this.navBg = {}
    }
  }

This is my typscript file. What is the reason for the error?
I got this error while developing a Clone project. I'm still in the learning phase

Please [edit] your question to specifically and clearly define the problem that you are trying to solve. Additional details — including all relevant code, error messages, and debugging logs — will help readers to better understand your problem and [what you are asking].

The issue you're encountering is likely due to a type mismatch in your Angular component. In Angular, the [ngStyle] directive expects an object of type { [key: string]: string | undefined | null } for the styles to apply. If you set navBg to any, it can potentially cause issues if it doesn't strictly adhere to this expected type.

@AgotaKristof - Please note that Generative AI (e.g., ChatGPT) is banned and read Help Center: AI policy. It is not permitted to use AI tools to generate or reword content that you post on Stack Overflow.

You must import either NgStyle or CommonModule for the directives, ngStyle or ngClass to work.

If it's standalone -> the imports should be in the imports array of the component.
If it's modular -> go to the module, where the component is added to the declarations array and add the import.

import { Component, HostListener } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule],
  styles: [`:host {height: 200vh;display:block;}`],
  template: `
    <h1 [ngStyle]="navBg">Hello from {{ name }}!</h1>
    <a target="_blank" href="https://angular.dev/overview">
      Learn more about Angular
    </a>
  `,
})
export class App {
  navBg: any;
  name = 'helo';

  @HostListener('document:scroll') scrollover() {
    if (document.body.scrollTop > 0 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 0) {
      this.navBg = {
        'background-color': '#000000',
      };
    } else {
      this.navBg = {};
    }
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);

Stackblitz Demo
